# what happen if i change oracle redo log file path after setting CDC?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We are trying to setup a data warehousing using Oracle 11g, its CDC feature with `HOTLOG_SOURCE` mode, tungsten tool for replication and `MariaDB`, replication was working fine for sometime,, but since we changed the path of archived log file oracle, replication stopped working.

Oracle is just generating large redo files but these are not being written on `MariaDB`.
So, my concern is: if we setup CDC on oracle schema and then change log file path, will it cause any problem?